# Why are the order statistics of a random sample not identically distributed?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Why are the order statistics of a random sample not identically distributed?

I understand that each order statistic is a different function of the random sample but how exactly does this imply that each order statistic has a distinct distribution to the the other order statistics?

Comment: Not following.  How could, say, the least element and the greatest element in the sample have the same distribution?  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: What makes you think they *are* identically distributed? Most variables are not, and that includes most functions of the same (set of) variables.

Comment: @Mees de Vries, I understand that there's no reason to believe that they are identically distributed but what \textit{ensures} that they do not have the same distribution?

Comment: @lulu Why wouldn't they have the same the distribution ?

Comment: Because the largest is bigger than the smallest.

Comment: Try an example.  Say my sample is the result of $100$ tosses of a fair die.  Then, with probability approaching $1$, the largest value I see is $6$ and the smallest is $1$.  Very low probability of getting anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Technically the order statistics could be identically distributed, if the variable $X$ whose order statistic we are computing is degenerate (i.e. takes a particular value with probability 1). If not, split the domain of $X$ into two sets $A$, $B$, with $a < b$ for all $a \in A, b \in B$ such that the original variable $X$ takes values in $A, B$ with positive probability. Then let $X^{(1)}, \ldots, X^{(n)}$ be the order statistics of $n > 2$ i.i.d. copies of $X$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(X^{(n)} \in A) = \mathbb P(X \in A)^n < \mathbb P(X \in A),
$$
while
$$
\mathbb P(X^{(1)} \in A) = 1 - \mathbb P(X^{(1)} \in B) = 1 - \mathbb P(X \in B)^n > 1 - \mathbb P(X \in B) = \mathbb P(X \in A).
$$
(You can do similar computations with the other order statistics, but they're a bit more involved.)